# Android - Why setClicable(true) sets item non-clicable and vice versa?

Tags: android, android-view

According to [developers' site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClickable%28boolean%29) `View.setClicable(true)` should

> make the view clickable, false otherwise

, so why is it reversed in real? Only `setClicable(false)` makes my View clicable. Have I found a mistake in API description?

**EVIDENCE:**

```
gridview.getChildAt(position).setClickable(true);
```

Feel free to try it at home. After this the child in gridview won't be clicable.

Comment: "Only setClicable(false) makes my View clicable" -- feel free to provide a reproducible test case demonstrating this.

Comment: I've tried it at the code provided, but I'm too normal to record a video of me clicking on it. ;-) It's for real, try it by yourself.

Comment: By "reproducible test case", I mean a project that demonstrates your claimed bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the clicking you're referring to is what you can listen to with an OnItemClickListener. This is handled entirely by the GridView (the GridView is also what draws the selector on the view), not the child view. You can control which items the GridView should consider as clickable with `isEnabled` in your adapter.

When you make the child view clickable it will handle all touch events over it. Because of this the GridView will not be notified of touch events on that view, and as such can't handle the click event.

So your view is perfectly clickable, you'd just have to use an OnClickListener to get notified of the clicks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood what is is saying. It says exactly what you said. You pass  true to make the view clickable or false otherwise (i.e to make it not clickable).

Comment: There was a small mistake in question, I'm sorry (midnight in here). setClicable(false) makes it clicable and setClicable(true) makes it non-clicable. Or it wouldn't be weird/wrong at all :-D

Comment: If that is the case then it is incorrect. But i doubt it is. Could be a bug of some such.

Comment: You can try it and see by yourself, it would be just a few lines of code.. But I admit, I could be wrong.